# Why am I getting "#1066 - Not unique table/alias"?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting:

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'user_account'

for the following. I have read all answers and I believe it should be fine.
What's the problem?

```
SELECT user_session.node_id, user_account.login_name
FROM user_session, user_account 
LEFT JOIN user_account ON user_account.id=user_session.user_id 
WHERE user_account.login_name="mike@rocketmail.com" OR user_account.login_name="mikeg@looxcicon.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on the `user_account` table twice.  This should work:

```
SELECT user_session.node_id, user_account.login_name 
FROM user_session
    LEFT JOIN user_account ON user_account.id=user_session.user_id 
WHERE user_account.login_name="mike@rocketmail.com" 
    OR user_account.login_name="mikeg@looxcicon.com"
```

Your query had:

```
FROM user_session, user_account 
    LEFT JOIN user_account
```

You can query the same table multiple times, but you'd need to add an alias.  I don't suppose that was your intention though.

BTW -- since you have `WHERE` criteria on the user_account table, no need for the `LEFT JOIN`.  I'd replace that with an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: @MikeGazit -- np, glad I could help.